# Session variable set before request is not accessible in Django view during tests

Tags: python, django, session

I need to store a kind of state between HTTP requests. Because I don't use the JS frontend, I decided to use session variables stored in cookies. My session settings look like below:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

I need a function to easily manipulate one session variable. Because this functionality is quite simple, I decided to exceptionally use function-based view:

```
def set_category_filter(request, pk):
    if pk == 0:
        if 'filter_category_id' in request.session:  # this is False during unit testing, but it's ok in a normal app run
            del request.session['filter_category_id']
    else:
        get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk, user=request.user)
        request.session['filter_category_id'] = pk
    return redirect('index')
```

The problem is I cannot test case when I want to unset this session variable. Suppose the session variable `filter_category_id` is set and I want to reset it. When I do this in my browser, everything works okay. When I try to do this via Django TestCase, it fails, because this session variable is not passed to request!

```
class SetCategoryFilterTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super().setUp()
        self.fake = Faker()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="testuser", password="12345")
        self.client.force_login(self.user)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.logout()

    # ...

    def test_unset_successfully(self):
        """Werify unsetting "filter_category_id" session field.

        Expected: Delete "filter_category_id" when url called with parameter 0
        """

        # GIVEN
        session = self.client.session
        session['filter_category_id'] = DUMMY_INT
        session.save()

        clear_arg = 0

        # WHEN
        self.client.get(reverse("filter_tasks_by_category", args=[clear_arg]))

        # THEN
        self.assertFalse("filter_category_id" in session)
```

As you see, I try to assume in the test, that the mentioned session variable is already set. Then I try to delete, but there are two problems:

1. During debugging, the condition `if 'filter_category_id' in request.session` is equal to `False`, so the session variable is not being unset.
2. After the request is done and code execution goes back to the test case, the session variable set on the beginning of the test case still exists so the test fails.

I tried to follow rule from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session) that we need to store session to variable before modification and call `save()` after. But it didn't help. Also, I read somewhere that it's better to do another request or at least `login()` in order to set the session object. But, as you see in `setUp()` method, the login is already done.

It doesn't help too when I try to perform another request to *ensure* that session has been created:

```
def test_unset_successfully(self):
    """Werify unsetting "filter_category_id" session field.

    Expected: Delete "filter_category_id" when url called with parameter 0
    """

    # GIVEN
    category = Category.objects.create(user=self.user, name=self.fake.name())
    self.client.get(reverse("filter_tasks_by_category", args=[category.id]))

    session = self.client.session
    session['filter_category_id'] = DUMMY_INT
    session.save()

    clear_arg = 0

    # WHEN
    self.client.get(reverse("filter_tasks_by_category", args=[clear_arg]))

    # THEN
    self.assertFalse("filter_category_id" in session)
```

This code is not only strange, but also it doesn't confirm the statement that I have to do a request first before accessing the session object.

Do you know how to deal with this situation? Basically all I want to do is to set a session variable and pass it with a request to my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that I need to update session cookie:

```
# GIVEN
session = self.client.session
session["filter_category_id"] = DUMMY_INT
session.save()

# After saving new session, it must be re-assigned to a session cookie
session_cookie_name = django_settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
self.client.cookies[session_cookie_name] = session.session_key
```

Solution found on https://kurzacz.com/writing-django-tests-for-session-variables-stored-in-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to test the delete part, use mocks:

```
def test_unset_successfully(self):
    request_mock = Mock()
    request_mock.session = {"filter_category_id": 123}

    set_category_filter(request_mock, 0)

    self.assertIsNone(request_mock.session.get("filter_category_id"))
```

Comment: Yes, this one looks like a nice replacement, but I guess it has potential pitfalls. This time, in fact, I only want to test dictionary modification. But another time I would need to do some more complicated operations on the session object. Thanks for your effort, you got my (+1)! But I would like to see how to manipulate this real session object.